# Grading a test - Loop checking radio input values (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, radio-group

I am working on an online test where you get your output directly. I get stuck at checking the values of the radio input with a loop. Why gives the checkFields function output undefined?

Javascript Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

//click button
$("#submitTest").click(function(){

//check if all answers are given
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (checkFields([i].toString())) {

//calculate total score
    if ($("input[name=[i]]").val() == aq[i]) {score = score + 1};
}

        else{alert("Please answer all questions");
        break}};

console.log(score);

//return level of English

}
)
//setFunction
function checkFields(Q){
    console.log(
    $("[name='[Q]']:checked").val())
}
//Set score 0
var score = 0;
//Answers
var aq1 = "a1";
var aq2 = "a1";
var aq3 = "a3";
var aq4 = "a2";
var aq5 = "a1";
var aq6 = "a2";
var aq7 = "a3";
var aq8 = "a3";
var aq9 = "a1";
var aq10 = "a1";
}
)
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- liberaries -->
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Form -->
    <form id="testEnglish">
        <!-- Q1 -->
        <p class="question">1. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="1" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="1" value="a2">a2<br>   
        <input type="radio" id="1" name="1" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q2 -->
        <p class="question">2. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="2" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q3 -->
        <p class="question">3. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="3" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q4 -->
        <p class="question">4. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="4" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="4" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="4" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q5 -->
        <p class="question">5. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="5" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="5" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="5" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q6 -->
        <p class="question">6. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="6" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="6" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="6" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q7 -->
        <p class="question">7. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="7" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="7" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="7" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q8 -->
        <p class="question">8. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="8" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="8" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="8" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q9 -->
        <p class="question">9. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="9" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="9" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="9" value="a3">a3
        <!-- Q10 -->
        <p class="question">10. Can I park here?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="10" value="a1">a1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="10" value="a2">a2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="10" value="a3">a3

    </form>
    <!-- Submit -->
    <button id="submitTest">Submit Test!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This code might not be the way to do it. I tried various ways but did not manage.

---

### edited below

New code

https://jsfiddle.net/5fnugrts/#&togetherjs=AOK0k8r4i2

HTML Code

```
<!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <!-- Libaries -->
          <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
          </head>
          <body>
          <!-- Form -->
          <form id="testEnglish">
            <div id="myForm"></div>
          </form>
          <!-- Submit button -->
          <button id="submitTest">Submit Test!</button>
```

Javascript Code

```
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //Answers and Questions constructor ("question","answer1","answer2","answer3","a"+number of correct answer)
    function Question(question, answer1, answer2, answer3, correctAnswer) {
      this.q = question;
      this.a1 = answer1;
      this.a2 = answer2;
      this.a3 = answer3;
      this.ca = correctAnswer;
    };
    //Answers and Questions ("question","answer1","answer2","answer3","a"+number of correct answer)
    var aQ = {
      Q1: new Question("What is the correct answer 1?", "Cheese", "Ham", "Turkey", "a1"),
      Q2: new Question("What is the correct answer 2?", "Cheese", "Ham", "Turkey", "a1"),
      Q3: new Question("What is the correct answer 3?", "Cheese", "Ham", "Turkey", "a2"),
      Q4: new Question("What is the correct answer 4?", "Cheese", "Ham", "Turkey", "a2"),
      Q5: new Question("What is the correct answer 5?", "Cheese", "Ham", "Turkey", "a3"),
    };
    //Set Setinhtml function ("name of radio group" "question","answer1","answer2","answer3","a"+number of correct answer)
    function appendQuestion(groupName, question, answer1, answer2, answer3) {
      $("div#myForm").append("<p class=\"question\">" + question + "</p>")
      $("div#myForm").append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"" + groupName + "\" value=\"a1\">" + answer1 + "<br>")
      $("div#myForm").append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"" + groupName + "\" value=\"a2\">" + answer2 + "<br>")
      $("div#myForm").append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"" + groupName + "\" value=\"a3\">" + answer3 + "<br>")
    };
    //Set in HTML loop
    for (i = 1; i <= Object.keys(aQ).length; i++) {
      appendQuestion([i],
        eval("aQ.Q" + [i] + ".q"),
        eval("aQ.Q" + [i] + ".a1"),
        eval("aQ.Q" + [i] + ".a2"),
        eval("aQ.Q" + [i] + ".a3"),
        eval("aQ.Q" + [i] + ".ca"))
    };
    //Sumbit answers
    $("#submitTest").click(function() {
      score = 0
        //Loop and give values
      for (i = 1; i <= Object.keys(aQ).length; i++) {
        tAnswer = $("input:radio[name ='" + i + "']:checked").val()
        cAnswer = eval("aQ.Q" + i + ".ca")
          //Check if answers are filled in
        if (!tAnswer) {
          alert("Please answer all questions");
          return;
        }
        //Check correct answers
        else if (tAnswer == cAnswer) {
          score++
        }
      }
      //Report score
      alert("Your score is " + score + "/" + Object.keys(aQ).length);
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: It's looking for a checkbox named Q. You need to build the string "[name='" + Q + "']:checked"

Comment: Awesome. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your code to make it more compact and effecient

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Maher-Fa/pen/jypjya)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   //Set score 0
   var score = 0;
   //Answers
   aq1 = "a1";
   aq2 = "a1";
   aq3 = "a3";
   aq4 = "a2";
   aq5 = "a1";
   aq6 = "a2";
   aq7 = "a3";
   aq8 = "a3";
   aq9 = "a1";
   aq10 = "a1";

   $("#submitTest").click(function() {
     score = 0
     for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
       tAnswer = $("input:radio[name ='" + i + "']:checked").val()
       cAnswer = window["aq"+i]
       if (!tAnswer) {
         alert("Please answer all questions");
         return;
       } else if (tAnswer == cAnswer) {
         console.log("#"+i+": correct")
         score++
       } else if (tAnswer != cAnswer) {
         console.log("#"+i+" incorrect")
       }
     }
    alert("Your score is "+ score +"/10");
   });
 });
```

`tAnswer` is the answer and `cAnswer` is the correct answer, you can also check `if(!cAnswer)` then you didn't define the correct answer.

Comment: I just noticed i used `break` when not all questions are answerd. This was a mistake since it will break the loop but will still continue with the rest of the function. Use `return` instead. I edited the answer.

Comment: Cheers. Could you explain the difference? And what does window["aq"+i] do? I replaced it - and edited the code so the HTML is generated by JS. See above.

Comment: If i = 1 `window["aq"+i]` refers to the variable named `aq1` this is needed because if we use `aq+i` the code will try to look for a var named `aq` and add the value of  `i` to it. As of the rest of your question I don't any changes in your code above